# Css media query when JavaScript disabled?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to use css @media query like this:

```
@media (javascript: disabled) { 
 body { color: red; } 
}
```

Or is there another way to do like this?

Comment: Do it the other way around. Add a class that JS is availbale.

Comment: Media Queries Level 5 has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/scripting, but no browser support yet.

Comment: A bit of basic research brings lots of approaches however, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4665748/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32514426/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35382266/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181340/1427878

Comment: As of recently all (major) browsers support the [@media scripting](https://caniuse.com/?search=scripting) query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most valid markup possible, you should be able to include this rule as part of a `<noscript>` block:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```